# Getting 404 on accessing Azure devops from Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-devops, axios, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a Node JS app, and I want to create a work item in Azure DevOps , I generated personal access token key with Read and Write permission for work item as shown in below image:
[image: Permission to work items]

Below are my code to access my work item from Node JS,and also installed axios for the purpose:

```
const axios = require('axios');

// Azure DevOps organization URL
const orgUrl = 'https://dev.azure.com/<organisationName>';

// Personal Access Token (PAT) with Work Item read/write scope
const pat = ''; // PAT generated with above permissions in devOps

// Project name
const projectName = 'ProjectName';

// Work item type (e.g., 'Task', 'User Story', etc.)
const workItemType = 'Task';

// Work item fields


async function createWorkItem(short_description, description, urgency, impact, assignment_group, caller_id, assigned_to) {
    const workItemData = {
        fields: {
            'System.Title': short_description,
            'System.AreaPath': projectName,
            'System.IterationPath': projectName,
            'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority': urgency,
            'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.State': 'To Do',
            'System.AssignedTo': assigned_to,
            // Add more fields as needed
        },
    };

    try {
        const url = `${orgUrl}/${projectName}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemType}?api-version=7.1`;
        console.log("COMPLETE URL: ",url);

        const response = await axios.post(url, [workItemData], {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(`:${pat}`).toString('base64')}`,
            },
        });

        console.log('Work item created successfully:', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating work item:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    }
}
```

When I try to access , I got 404 (page not found):
[image: 404 error]

My complete URL generated in above code:
**https://dev.azure.com/OrganisationName/ProjectName/_apis/wit/workitems/Task?api-version=7.1**

As I am new to this, any help will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 404 error means that the Rest API URL has issue.

Refer to the doc about the Rest API to create the work item: [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=7.1-preview.3
```

We need to add the `$` before the work item type parameter.

To solve this issue, you need to add the `$` character before the work item type parameter.

For example:

```
const workItemType = '$Task';
```

Full Sample:

```
const axios = require('axios');

// Azure DevOps organization URL
const orgUrl = 'https://dev.azure.com/<organisationName>';

// Personal Access Token (PAT) with Work Item read/write scope
const pat = ''; // PAT generated with above permissions in devOps

// Project name
const projectName = 'ProjectName';

// Work item type (e.g., 'Task', 'User Story', etc.)
const workItemType = '$Task';

// Work item fields


async function createWorkItem(short_description, description, urgency, impact, assignment_group, caller_id, assigned_to) {
    const workItemData = {
        fields: {
            'System.Title': short_description,
            'System.AreaPath': projectName,
            'System.IterationPath': projectName,
            'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority': urgency,
            'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.State': 'To Do',
            'System.AssignedTo': assigned_to,
            // Add more fields as needed
        },
    };

    try {
        const url = `${orgUrl}/${projectName}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemType}?api-version=7.1`;
        console.log("COMPLETE URL: ",url);

        const response = await axios.post(url, [workItemData], {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
                'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(`:${pat}`).toString('base64')}`,
            },
        });

        console.log('Work item created successfully:', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating work item:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    }
}
```

**Note:** You also need to set the `'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',` in the headers.

**Result:**

[image]

**Update:**

```
const axios = require('axios');

// Azure DevOps organization URL
const orgUrl = 'https://dev.azure.com/organization';

// Personal Access Token (PAT) with Work Item read/write scope
const pat = ''; // PAT generated with above permissions in devOps

// Project name
const projectName = 'xx';

// Work item type (e.g., 'Task', 'User Story', etc.)
const workItemType = '$Task';

// Work item fields


let data = JSON.stringify([
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }
]);

    try {
        const url = `${orgUrl}/${projectName}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemType}?api-version=7.1`;
        console.log("COMPLETE URL: ",url);
        
        const response =  axios.post(url, data, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
                'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(`:${pat}`).toString('base64')}`,
            },
        });

        console.log('Work item created successfully:', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating work item:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Kevin Lu-MSFT , getting **path cannot be null ** , even after doing your suggested code changes.  Error creating work item: {
  '$id': '1',
  innerException: null,
  message: 'Path cannot be null.',
  typeName: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common',
  typeKey: 'VssPropertyValidationException',
  errorCode: 0,
  eventId: 3000
}

Comment: @Pam Can you try the complete code in my update of the answer? I use this code and it can work.

Comment: @Pam From your node sample, it seems that the request body format of the Rest API has some issues. You can try to use my  updated sample in the answer

Comment: yes your updated code works, and work Item is created on Azure DevOps.

Comment: @Pam Glad to know that the script can work for you. If the answer can help, you can consider accepting it